# How to modify mpld3 LinkedView plugin to plot multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

I would like to modify the LinkedView plugin from this example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins, utils


class LinkedView(plugins.PluginBase):
    """A simple plugin showing how multiple axes can be linked"""

    JAVASCRIPT = """
    mpld3.register_plugin("linkedview", LinkedViewPlugin);
    LinkedViewPlugin.prototype = Object.create(mpld3.Plugin.prototype);
    LinkedViewPlugin.prototype.constructor = LinkedViewPlugin;
    LinkedViewPlugin.prototype.requiredProps = ["idpts", "idline", "data"];
    LinkedViewPlugin.prototype.defaultProps = {}
    function LinkedViewPlugin(fig, props){
        mpld3.Plugin.call(this, fig, props);
    };

    LinkedViewPlugin.prototype.draw = function(){
      var pts = mpld3.get_element(this.props.idpts);
      var line = mpld3.get_element(this.props.idline);
      var data = this.props.data;

      function mouseover(d, i){
        line.data = data[i];
        line.elements().transition()
            .attr("d", line.datafunc(line.data))
            .style("stroke", this.style.fill);
      }
      pts.elements().on("mouseover", mouseover);
    };
    """

    def __init__(self, points, line, linedata):
        if isinstance(points, matplotlib.lines.Line2D):
            suffix = "pts"
        else:
            suffix = None

        self.dict_ = {"type": "linkedview",
                      "idpts": utils.get_id(points, suffix),
                      "idline": utils.get_id(line),
                      "data": linedata}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)

# scatter periods and amplitudes
np.random.seed(0)
P = 0.2 + np.random.random(size=20)
A = np.random.random(size=20)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
data = np.array([[x, Ai * np.sin(x / Pi)]
                 for (Ai, Pi) in zip(A, P)])
points = ax[1].scatter(P, A, c=P + A,
                       s=200, alpha=0.5)
ax[1].set_xlabel('Period')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Amplitude')

# create the line object
lines = ax[0].plot(x, 0 * x, '-w', lw=3, alpha=0.5)
ax[0].set_ylim(-1, 1)

ax[0].set_title("Hover over points to see lines")

# transpose line data and add plugin
linedata = data.transpose(0, 2, 1).tolist()
plugins.connect(fig, LinkedView(points, lines[0], linedata))

mpld3.show()
```

to plot multiple lines in the same axis for each point. So if I, for example, extend the data to also include a cosine curve

```
data = np.array([[x, Ai * np.sin(x / Pi), Ai * np.cos(x / Pi)] for (Ai, Pi) in zip(A, P)])
```

how do I get the plugin to display both the sine and cosine curves over each other? I guess I could do it manually by creating a second line object, but surely there is a better way.